# Understanding gdaltindex Limitations?

Tags: gdal, limitations, gdaltindex

I was wondering if there is a size, or count limitation with gdaltindex. I ran the operation from within OSGeo4W via a Python script, and from within QGIS 2.2 (Windows) and had issues processing a directory with 880 GeoTiffs. The file size of the tiffs are ~ 205MB each. However, when I processed a sub-sample (four tiffs) the operation ran perfect, from within QGIS and OSGeo4W.